# Filter df within same date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a weekly report, where I need to find duplicates of IDs in one column (Customer ID) happening within the same date range (Submit Date).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.read_excel('report.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', parse_dates=['Submit Date'])
customer = report['Customer ID']

submit_date = report['Submit Date']
submit_date = submit_date.dt.date
submit_date.sort_index(inplace=True)

mask1 = customer.duplicated(keep=False) == True
report = report[mask1]
```

And this part comes easy - I have the result of all duplicated IDs. However, I'm not sure how should I approach the problem of limiting it to the same day, ex 2021-04-12, so I can have only duplicates in this particular date. I tried creating for loop, where there is if statement checking

```
if day < day + timedelta(days=1)
```

but that didn't seem to bring any results. I could hard code the dates so create a different masks for every separate date of week but I'd like to keep the report automated.

Thanks in advance for all ideas!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in the same format as `report.xlsx`. e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Submit Date': ['2020-01-01', '2021-03-05'], 'Customer ID': [1, 2]})`

Comment: See here for some information about creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that a mask is essentially just a boolean Series. So, you could create a date mask: `date_mask = report['Submit Date'] == '2021-04-12'`. Assuming that the date field has been properly loaded as a pandas datetime field, this will create a mask which will filter only data with that date. You can find the intersection of two masks using `&`: `date_mask & mask1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to sort it out:

```
while start_date <= end_date:
same_date_values = report.loc[start_date == submit_date]
print(f" ################# DATE CHECKED: {start_date} #################")

mask1 = same_date_values['Customer ID'].duplicated(keep=False) == True
same_date_values = same_date_values[mask1]

df = df.append(same_date_values)

start_date += timedelta(days=1)
```

It's a one while loop and I'm missing a  after declaration of loop but this basically allowed me to iterarte through every day (12-04, 13-4, etc.) and break it into smaller dataframes with same date.